# Multithreading of roles in loop

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that loops over a list of devices.
The run time of the playbook can get very long (depending on the number of devices in the list).
I thought of parallelisation of the roles.
Is there an option to call the role for a number of devices at the same time?

```
- name: Loop over List of Nodes
  include_role:
    name: reports
    tasks_from: get_reports_for_node
  vars:
    node_dn: "topology/{{ node_id }}"
  loop: "{{ node_list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: node_id
```

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Can you share the content of the role? Especially the mentioned task. Maybe it is possible to provide an answer then.

Answer (score 3):

You would typically achieve tasks concurrency with [Ansible async tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html), however as per https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/19083, `include_role` nor `import_role` support async tasks. I have just checked the current documentation of those tasks, given that's an old ticket, and it states there that `async` is still not supported.

What I would probably do is to implement the async tasks within the referenced role rather than from the higher level playbook,

Comment: I think if those tasks are such as win_copy, win_unzip, and many others, async also doesnt work with those.  So the whole idea of putting them to another role was for exactly that reason, to run them in async somehow.  Now sure how i can get the "backup" tasks to run in async so they dont hold up the pipeline yet..